# HTML form remembering previous input

Tags: php, html

I know this was explained before but whenever I use lines like:

```
php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name'];
```

It displays that in the text box.  I have the PHP file setup to verify if both a firstname and lastname are submitted.  However I want it to keep whichever box had input to remain in it for example:

---

First name:John

Last name:

---

so that when the form displays

---

YOU DID NOT ENTER A LAST NAME

First name:John

Last name:

---

The first name is still remembered

Comment: `<input type="text" name"firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name']))  echo $_POST['name']; ?>"`

Comment: Short tag syntax might be more useful.  `<?= (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Beware that if you just do simple `echo $_POST['firstname']` people can do some nasty things with your inputs (like posting javascript and having fun with javascript `alert()` function.

So, you shoud encapsulate the input like this

```
echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['firstname']))
```

Full example html + PHP on one input field:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value=" <?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['firstname'])); ?>" />
```

If `$_POST` is empty that code will output nothing. If user posted something, that code will display is *safely*.

Answer (score -1):

When you collect the $_POST data, add it also to the $_SESSION array (you'll need to call session_start(), first, of course, at the top of the handling script).

Then when they return to the page on an error, you can do the same isset() call you have in your example with $_SESSION instead of $_POST.

Example handler code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_POST) {

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = 
    $_POST['firstname']    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "firstname", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //etc.
}
```

Comment: So $_SESSION corresponds to session_start.  Why does it not have an equal sign and what does filter_input, INPUT_POST and FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING do? I just feel like there maybe an easier way of doing it but what do i know

Comment: "Not have an equals sign"?  It does.  Multiple assignment:  $foo = $bar = something(); (don't let the newline/format confuse you).   I'm setting both $_SESSION['firstname'] and $_POST['firstname'] to the value returned by filter_input, which is now the recommended way to access raw data from the POST array, instead of just $foo = $_POST['something'];